# UITableView returns null?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios4, init

I have spent many hours looking into this and I still can't find a solution. Here's a chart on what the user goes through:

- The user takes a picture or takes one from their camera roll
- As soon as they take (or select) one, the captionView closes
- As soon as the captionView closes, startUploads from a different view starts
- If the user decides to open the view that startUploads is in, they can see what has been uploaded

Now that you know a little bit about the process, I have a few issues. When uploads finish I want them to fade out. I know how to do that, but for some reason when I call to, the `self.theTableView` returns null. I have a `@property (nonatomic, retain)...` in my .h and I have a `@sythesize theTableView;` in my .m.

In a different question, I found out that when doing the `startUploads`, my NSMutableArray needed to be initiated in here (so I thought that it would do the same with my UItableView). Here's what I have:

```
- (id)initWithNibNamed:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)bundle {
self = [super initWithNibNamed:nibName bundle:bundle];
if (self) {
    processList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.theTableView = [[UITableView alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"thetableview: %@", theTableView);
}
return self;
}
```

Just in case you want to see how `startUploads` is called, here's the code:

```
processViewController *testtest = [[processViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"processView.xib" bundle:nil];
//testtest.processList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithNig];
NSLog(@"Different:displayProcessVC BEFORE STARTING UPLOAD, processList = %@", testtest.processList);
NSLog(@"Different:displayProcessVC BEFORE STARTING UPLOAD, theTableView = %@", testtest.theTableView);
[testtest startUploads];
NSLog(@"Different:displayProcessVC AFTER STARTING UPLOAD, processList = %@", testtest.processList);
NSLog(@"Different:displayProcessVC AFTER STARTING UPLOAD, theTableView = %@", testtest.theTableView);
[testtest release];
```

However it still shows `(null)` in the console.

Please help!
Coulton

**EDIT 1:**

Here's where it's being nil:

```
- (void)deleteOneRow: (NSString *)theString {
int theInt = [processList indexOfObject:theString];
[processList removeObjectAtIndex:theInt];
NSArray *deleteIndexPaths = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:theInt inSection:0], nil];
NSLog(@"theTableView: %@", self.theTableView);
[self.theTableView beginUpdates];
[self.theTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:deleteIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[self.theTableView endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: Are you using a default UITableViewController? Also, you seem to be leaking memory in your init function.

Comment: theTableView is also being leaked…Where are you referencing theTableview that it shows nil?

Comment: @Moshe: It's a UIViewController. `@interface processViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {` I make both nil in my dealloc like this: `- (void)dealloc { self.processList = nil; self.theTableView = nil; [super dealloc]; }`. I can't see anywhere else it's leaking?

Comment: What's happening to the table view in between?

Comment: @phpnerd—the value you're assigning to theTableView is retained, but never released. The release in dealloc is simply balancing the retain of the property, but not the init of the table view.

Comment: @Inspire48: I would post it but it's really long and you probably won't want to look through it - so I'll give a summary: searches the database for pictures to upload, resizes a picture, replace spaces with special string for the caption, upload file to server, if it was successful delete, if not display an error.

Comment: @Inspire48: So do something like this `self.theTableView = [[UITableView alloc] init];
  [self.theTableView release];` in my `initWithNibNamed`? It doesn't work. Same issue.

Comment: Erm…the cause of the nil doesn't seem to be apparent in the code. Are you not using IB? Trying creating a XIB for the view and hooking up the table view as an outlet. As far as the memory goes, you're leaking, not over-retaining, so that's a separate issue. You'll have to alloc/init the table view as a variable, assign the variable, then release the variable:

`UITableView *tv = [[UITableView alloc] init];
self.theTableView = tv;
[tv release];`

Or bypass the property, in which case you *won't* retain it an extra time.

Comment: I am using an IBOutlet to connect my UITableView.

Comment: …If the outlet's been set, then `self.theTableView = [[UITableView alloc] init];` isn't a necessary line. I'm still convinced you're doing something to the table view in between. If it's connected in IB, you shouldn't be setting anything else to the property; in that case, the table view itself shouldn't be nil. Ever. Until the view controller itself is unloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The designated initializer for UITableView is `-initWithFrame:style:` and you're leaking. Try this in `-viewDidLoad` instead.

`self.theTableView = [[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame style:UITableViewStylePlain] autorelease];`

Comment: Put it in my viewDidLoad and commented it out, still returned `(null)`. My UITableView is a IBAction and connected in interface builder, if that makes any difference. I am thinking it's not getting called or something because of the `startUploads` when the view hasn't loaded?